# How can I configure IIS to save log files in a given folder without creating a W3SVCXXX folder under it?

Tags: iis, logging, iis-7.5

You can configure IIS to save its logs in any folder you want; however, even if you configure this setting at the site level, it will always create another folder under the one you choose, called `W3SVCXXX`, where `XXX` is the site ID.

Is it possible to configure IIS to save its logs in a given folder *without creating a `W3SVCXXX` folder under it*?

Comment: not as far as I know, but why are you trying to accomplish this for?

Comment: Maybe use LINKD.EXE to create a junction from path Y to the W3SVCXXX path?

Answer (score 0):

IIS does not offer that level of customization by default. If you configure it to log per site, it will create a W3SVC# folder based on the Site ID. You can configure IIS to have one log per server instead, if that will suit your purposes.

A more elaborated alternative is to use the [Advanced Logging](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/advanced-logging) extension.